# Dynamic Karma running

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am using Karma to run unit test for my AngularJS project and I have configure `karma.conf.js` to run complete test of whole application. The problem is as my project grow big, the list of test to be run become long. This make the Karma unit test become unpractical as every-time need to wait a long time for it to complete all test whenever changes to the code.

As my project structure in the way that every different module is put in the each independent folder. So, I am thinking is there a way to dynamically run the test only on the folder with the file changes? Meaning, for example if there is file changes in `Module A` folder, then Karma automatically run all the test in that folder only. This way the test will run much faster.